# ruby on rails + best_in_place + datatables + haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, datatables, best-in-place

DataTables editing example (using best_in_place)

This example shows how to create editable tables using datatables.net and best_in_place.

Currently Datatables.net only has example for using JediTables jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gemfile:

```
gem "best_in_place"
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
```

app/views/schedules/index.html.haml:

```
%table
  - @schedules.each do |s|
    %tr
      %td= best_in_place s, :name
:javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Activating Best In Place */
  jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
});
```

Comment: Hello, can you please assist with the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007030/datatables-with-best-in-place-not-allowing-updating