# Datatables with best_in_place not allowing updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, best-in-place

I am attempting to use best_in_place with datatables to allow for updating of table entries in-line. However, I have everything rendering correctly and can edit the entry, the change does not persist and same to the database and throws the log below. At present I am just looking to edit the store id and address information:

```
Started PUT "/locations/104" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-02 16:15:17 -0400
Started PUT "/locations/104" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-02 16:15:17 -0400
Processing by LocationsController#update as JSON
Processing by LocationsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"location"=>{"address"=>"90000"}, "authenticity_token"=>"B0Eshgp8
OCRi5YJQOs+orNRo9VOMmRgyaO4fc3nEDzs=", "id"=>"104"}
  Parameters: {"location"=>{"address"=>"90000"}, "authenticity_token"=>"B0Eshgp8
OCRi5YJQOs+orNRo9VOMmRgyaO4fc3nEDzs=", "id"=>"104"}
  ←[1m←[36mLocation Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `locations`.* FROM `locations`
WHERE `locations`.`id` = 104 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[36mLocation Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `locations`.* FROM `locations`
WHERE `locations`.`id` = 104 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  BEGIN
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  BEGIN
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mCOMMIT←[0m
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mCOMMIT←[0m
Completed 204 No Content in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Completed 204 No Content in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[2015-05-02 16:15:17] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body.
 Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

locations.html.erb:

```
<% if @restaurant.locations.any? %>

    <h1>Manage <%= @restaurant.name.pluralize %> Restaurant Locations</h1>

  <button id="deleteLocations">Delete Restaurant</button>
  <button id="selectAllLocations">Select All</button>
  <button id="deSelectAllLocations">Deselect All</button>
    <table id="restaurantLocations" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>id</th>
            <th>Store Number</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip Code</th>
        <th>Major City Bidding</th>
            <th>Sit Down?</th>
            <th>Drive Through?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot id="input">
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Store Number</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zip Code</th>
        <th>Major City Bidding</th>
        <th>Sit Down?</th>
        <th>Drive Through?</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <%# current_user.locations.each do |branch| %>
    <tbody>
      <% @restaurant.locations.where(removed: 0).each do |branch| %>
            <tr>
          <td><%= branch.id %></td>
                <td><%= best_in_place branch, :store_number %></td>
                <td><%= best_in_place branch, :address %></td>
                <td><%= branch.city_name %></td>
                <td><%= branch.state.upcase %></td>
                <td><%= branch.zip %></td>
          <td><%= City.where(id: branch.city_id).pluck(:city).first %></td>
                <td><%= branch.sit_down %></td>
                <td><%= branch.drive_through %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
    </table>
<% else %>
    <h1>Upload <%= @restaurant.name.pluralize %> Restaurant Locations</h1>
    <p>Simply format your CSV file as the sample:(INSERT EXAMPLE) and upload</p>
<% end %>
```

location controller:

```
  def update
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    @location.update(params[:address])
    respond_with @location
  end

  private
    def location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:address)
    end
```

locations.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  console.log("locations.coffee loaded")
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

Comment: Did you solve this? Could you post the answer?

Comment: Apparently his eye is not upon you...